# display video from database into gridview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I would like to display video from database into a grid view i managed to do it with images but have no idea how to do it with a videoview , i would like to do the same but for videos

```
public class Photoadapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList<Photo> photoList;



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return photoList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return photoList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewList);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final Photo photo = photoList.get(position);
        final byte[] photoImage = photo.getImage();
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoImage, 0, photoImage.length);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return row;
    }


    public Photoadapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Photo> photoList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.photoList = photoList;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you written the code for videoview

Comment: not yet have no  idea how to start

Comment: Is your video URL as a http://... or from Raw folder?

Comment: Follow this Tutorial: [VideoViewTutorial](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/content/unit-5-advanced-graphics-and-views/lesson-13-media/13-1-p-playing-video-with-videoview/13-1-p-playing-video-with-videoview.html)